# Did Superman know Batman's identity in Batman: Hush?

Tags: dc-animated-movie-universe, batman-hush

In the animated movie ***Batman: Hush*** (2019), Clark Kent and Bruce Wayne meet with each other when Bruce comes to give an interview to Lois Lane. In this movie, does Superman know about the identity of Batman, namely that he is Bruce Wayne?

Comment: I can't help but recommend the comic book this story is based on at this point. It's worth reading, the storyline and art is great plus some more details and further fleshed out arcs are included. I hope you have fun and like the material. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes.**

For the long answer, you may or may not know that it's part of the canon know as [DC Animated Movie Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Animated_Movie_Universe), so everything that happened in previous films still canon to this one.

In *Justice League: War (2014)*:

During a fight between Green Lantern/Batman vs Superman, Batman calls Superman "Clark"
and in return Superman use his X-Ray vision and call him "Bruce Wayne". Batman didn't even try to hide his identity as in the previous scene he even told his secret identity to Green Lantern Hal Jordan.

Video for the same:

Comment: Slight mistake, no? Batman reveals his identity to GL at the end of the movie (not before the Superman/Batman/GL fight), before he gets taken by a Parademon to get Superman back

Answer (score 3):

Yes. In this story, Batman and Superman know each other's identity.

But they don't work together. Because Batman believes that Superman is too soft on the criminals, and Superman believes that Batman is too aggressive in the way he works.

However, they do respect each other and because of that, they have an agreement that they both stay in their respective cities. That is why Bruce came to Metropolis under the guise of an interview with Lois: to honor the agreement he has with Superman, but still, be able to continue his investigation.

Comment: what agreement? which film they made it?